# restrict the user from typing a new name and allow only to select from existing list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on autocomplete textbox feature of angularjs. I want the user only to select name from the existing autocomplete list instead of typing a new name. Eg.,When user types `'Al'` autocomplete list shows the matching list and user can select one name from the existing list instead of typing a new name.How to restrict user from submitting a new name which is not present in the existing list.

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/AdmtP1b6K9kQorMHmt7t?p=preview

Code Sample:

```
    $scope.countryList = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua &amp; Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei"];
$scope.validateField = function(){
  alert("Clicked on submit , validte field");
}
    $scope.complete=function(string){

        var output=[];
        angular.forEach($scope.countryList,function(country){
            if(country.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase())>=0){
                output.push(country);
            }
        });
        $scope.filterCountry=output;
    }
    $scope.fillTextbox=function(string){
        $scope.country=string;
        $scope.filterCountry=null;
    }
```

Any inputs would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable submit button and also highlight the border of the input field red, telling user to select name from drop down list.

First you need to update your `complete()` function. Use an `else if` statement that will check if the value is from the list or not, if not then you can implement your desired logic in that `else if` statement.

This method is flexible and easy to customize your error generation messages. You can show and hide the `div` that has the error message or you can apply css `style` on input-field using `ng-style` or `ng-class`. Right now I'll show you how to disable or enable button. Here is the updated code snippet:

```
 $scope.complete = function(string) {

    var output = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.countryList, function(country) {
      if (country.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
        output.push(country);
        $scope.enableDisable = false;
      } else if (country.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
        $scope.enableDisable = true;
      }
    });

    $scope.filterCountry = output;
  }
```

And the In the html section you just need to add ng-disabled attribute and set its value.

```
 <input type="submit" value="submit" ng-disabled="enableDisable" ng-click="validateField()">
```

So, you can do whatever you want in that `else if` statement to get the desire error message.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this plunkr.](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/XaUhARHhqm5QxGEm)

you can check for the validity of input using something like below and monitoring the value using `ng-change`

```
    $scope.checkInput = function(){
        $scope.validInput = $scope.countryList.indexOf($scope.country) > -1;
    }
```